# Determinining when no key is pressed in Java

Tags: java, key-events

How can I basically get the opposite of a key event?

IE a simple program will print out "Whatever" until any key is pressed, then stop.

After the key is released, it will start printing out again?

```
public class Printer
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
     "WHILE ANY KEYBOARD KEY NOT PRESSED" PRINT SOMETHING
     "WHEN PRESSED" STOP PRINTING SOMETHING
     " WHEN RELEASED" START PRINTING AGAIN
   }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? We can't really help you without knowing where you're stuck. If you need step-by-step directions, this really isn't the place for that. I'm flagging as too broad.

Comment: Java console support doesn't provide "key press" functionality, it requires the user to Rees he [Enter] key. Without using JNI/JNA style solution, you'd have to resort to using a Swing/AWT based GUI solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can print in the main thread while checking on a boolean (lets say "isKeyPressed" which will be initially false) in while loop whenever a key pressed in the key listener you will set the boolean flag to true which will prevent the main thread from printing and when key released is fired, you wil set the boolean flag to false again to resume Printing

in main method

```
while(!isKeyPressed){
your logic / printing
}
```

in your keypressed listener

```
 public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    isKeyPressed = true;
}
```

in your keyReleased listener

```
 public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    isKeyPressed = false;
}
```

Hope that will help you.

Comment: It would need to count key press and release events otherwise multiple overlapping key events will confuse it.

Comment: This could "choke" the system; assumes the op needs to use Swing (or AWR) to monitor for key strokes, sch was unclear from he question and just as easily be achieved with a Swing Timer